# When to start worry over rows in database table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm constructing a database that will grow fast. Some tables will contain several millions of rows within a year. When should I start to worry over the database size?

Is a table with 30 million rows impossible to handle? How is this usually solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several million rows is not that large. Creating appropriate indexes for your query work load will keep things fast.

The (loose) rule of thumb with SQL Server is that you should consider partitioning at around the 20 - 30 million row mark. [*Assuming you have Enterprise Edition of SQL Server in Production*. But partitioning is not always the solution.]

- [Partitioned Table and Index Concepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188232.aspx)
- [Partitioned Table and Index Strategies Using SQL Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578580%28SQL.100%29.aspx)
- [SQL Server Partitioning: Not the Best Practices for Everything](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/06/sql-server-partitioning-not-the-answer-to-everything/)

Answer (score 1):

Properly tuned tables can handle billions of rows, so don't worry 8-)
I have several tables in my production project with > 1.5 billion rows each

**BUT - yes!**

Its taking more time to handle and maintain these tables

Comment: you have several tables with > 1,500, 000, 000 rows?

Comment: @MitchWheat yes, wanna talk about this? 8-) I working in company which produces 1.5+ million PAPER documents per day, and most of them have its electronic incarnation, and many of the documents are ONLY in electronic form. Most of the both types of documents are for tax departments - so we cannot just drop them after use 8-)

Comment: @MitchWheat 2 identical servers as: 24 core @ 128 Gb RAM, Storage - Hitachi SAN which allows 800 Mb/sec on 24 channels simultaneously and 300 Mb/sec on 150 channels simultaneously. StorageTec backup library ~ 800 Tb space. Yearly upgrade cost of HI-end hitachi storage is about 2.5-3 M$. Thats all you want to know? Oh yes - it is about 100-300 requests for data per second and over 3000 virtual users

Comment: @MitchWheat Hitachi is - AMS2300 (middle end), USPVm, NSC55 (both hi-end) all three stands are connected into supernode and uses the same cache

Comment: @MitchWheat One more Hitachi stand just bought - VSP